# using a Whirlpool that perfoms the first cycle ok fill, agigation, empty, and spin but only fills for rinse and stops. model# is LA9200XWN1

Tags: repair

using a Whirlpool that perfoms the first cycle ok fill, agitation, empty, and spin but only fills for rinse and stops. model# is LA9200XWN1 Would like suggested causes

Comment: How long have you waited for it to start?  There is a delay.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. When did this start happening?